# Why don't the electric field vectors cancel each other out in a non-conducting infinite plane sheet?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, vectors, gauss-law

[image][image]Why do these vectors not cancel each other out in spite of their being in the opposite directions?

Comment: Hi Jay. Can you clarify exactly what you are asking? Do you mean an infinite charged sheet? If so, where do you think the vectors will cancel. At the mid plane of the sheet? If you would like to draw a diagram and upload it to an image hosting site we can insert the diagram into your question to help clarify it.

Comment: As shown in the image above the electric field vectors are going in opposite directions above and below the plane.

Comment: The upwards field exists only above the sheet and the downwards field exists only below the sheet. The only place where both the two fields exist is right in the centre of the sheet, and in that plane they do cancel. Everywhere else they can't cancel because they don't overlap.

Comment: Consider it being point charges smeared across the plate. The field lines are supposedly propagating off the same set of charged particles in all directions, and the approximate resultant vector direction is the upward and downward. Try drawing a set of positive point charges horizontally and then resolve the approximate directions of their net combined field effect.

Comment: The vectors are in opposite sides still we add them algebraically to get total flux. I mean they are in opposite directions then why don't we add them vectorially?

Comment: Added a pic from my textbook if it helps.

Comment: If you want to quote a part of your text, please type it out rather than posting a picture. The relevant information won't show up if other people search for a similar question if it is in a picture.

Answer (score 3):

In order to superimpose two or more electric fields, they must be defined in the same region. In other words
$$\mathbf E=\mathbf E_1(x_0,y_0)+\mathbf E_2(x_0,y_0)$$
for some point in space $(x_0,y_0)$

In your case, $\mathbf E_1$ and $\mathbf E_2$ exist in different regions of space. Therefore, you can't superimpose them and they don't cancel. It's kind of like asking if I put my car in drive and your put yours in reverse why both of our cars don't just stay still.

Perhaps your confusion lies in thinking that the field vectors in your picture only exist on the sheet. This is not the case. At every point $(x,y,z)$ in space there is an electric field. For $z>0$ the field points upward, for $z<0$ the field points downward. You can't add the upward and downward fields together because they exist in different regions of space.

Comment: Then how and why are we adding them up?

Comment: @JaySen We aren't adding them up. That's what I'm trying to say. The two fields that you say should cancel out exist in different regions of space, so they don't add up and don't cancel

Comment: I think we add them up for getting the total electric field.

Comment: When doing field line vector resolution, we aren't adding the field or field lines itself, but the effect vector direction of the field(s).

Comment: Sorry but i haven't understood this yet.

Comment: You don't add the electric fields but you compute the total flux. The fields does not cancel when you compute the flux because the normal of the Gaussian closed surface change of direction in the two regions.

Comment: @VincentFraticelli I'm not sure who the comment is for, but the question if asking about why the vectors do not cancel out. I'm not sure if you are telling me to edit part of my answer or not

Comment: @JaySen To add electric field vectors together they have to exist at the same point in space. In this case there is only upward pointing field above the plate and only downward pointing field below the plate. There isn't additional upward field below the plate or downward field above the plate. Therefore, the field on either side of the plate does not cancel.

Comment: @AaronStevens It was not for you. I thought that may be the OP was making a confusion between adding the vectors and adding the flux ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a inside look at the atomic scale:

[image]

The field effect is radial and the intersecting field effects sort of cancles out. The direction lines are not forces on the plate but the field effect direction from the plate. You only do that sort of vector cancellation if the force vectors are rather on the plate. If another lone floating positively charged particle falls anywhere in this region, those field lines are the direction of force on the charge. We aren't vectorially resolving the field lines, but rather the force effect on another charged body.